# Using X11 to run a GUI python script from a BeagleBone

Tags: ssh, x11, beagleboneblack

I'm using XQuartz on a mac laptop to ssh in to a Beaglebone and have the BeagleBone run a python script with a GUI. The trick is that I want the GUI to run on a different display connected to the BB, not on my laptop display. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: When I run

```
ssh -X root@localhost
```

and then run my python script, I get the GUI back on my laptop. I want the GUI to appear on the monitor connected to the BeagleBone.

Comment: VNC is probably the way.

Comment: I am using XQuartz. Will that do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just type `DISPLAY=:0 python yourscript.py` (or don't use `-X`). When you `ssh -X` ssh daemon creates a local server listening on some port 6000 + offset ( say, 10) and sets `DISPLAY` variable to point to that port ( DISPLAY=:10 is a way to tell X clients "connect to tcp port 6010" ).